# A reference for finding a theorem

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request

I want a reference to find the proof of the following Theorem on real analysis:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Any decent ("non-baby") analysis text covering Riemann integration should have a proof. (For example, Bartle and Sherbert's *Introduction to real Analysis*, in Appendix C.)

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Integrability.